# In Azure Search how can I filter records that have tags with IDs matching any in a list

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

Given the following search index document schema:

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "Id": "abc",
            "Name": "Some name",  
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Id": "123",
                    "Name": "Tag123"
                },
                {
                    "Id": "456",
                    "Name": "Tag456"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Id": "xyz",
            "Name": "Some name",  
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Id": "123",
                    "Name": "Tag123"
                },
                {
                    "Id": "789",
                    "Name": "Tag789"
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

What is the correct syntax for an OData query that will return all records with any Tag/Ids that are contained in input list?

The closest I have got is:

```
Tags/any(object: object/Id search.in ('123,456,789'))
```

Comment: Could you clarify what "tags that contain any from the input list" means? Is it tags with any value of Id?

Comment: Yes, thats right

Comment: Got it, this query should return docs where its tags have some non-empty value:
{
    "search": "*",
    "filter": "search.ismatch('/.*/', 'Tags/Id', 'full', 'all')",
    "select": "Tags/Id"
}
Docs for ismatch: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-odata-full-text-search-functions#examples

Let me know if that helps.